# Why is a disabled button clickable?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, mouseevent

This case is using C# WPF. I want to instantly disable a button after clicking it to prevent clicking it twice in short succession. I disabled the button in `OnClick_Event` but still clickable.

Part of source is as below.

```
private void Button_Click_UpdateBurndownChart(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if(threadNotWorking)
   {
      updateButton.IsEnabled = false;
      startWorkThread();
   }
}

private void startWorkThread()
{
     ... ...
    //after finish required process
    updateButton.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: What happens if to test you comment out startWorkThread? I suspect it executes a loop that stops Windows messages being processed. If that's the case you should use a background worker thread (or insert Application.DoEvents in the loop as a crappy but easy solution).

Comment: you could just bind the buttons `IsEnabled` property to `threadNotWorking`

Comment: The mouse click gets added to the message queue.  And is stuck there until startWorkThread() returns and your code re-enters the dispatcher loop.  At which point the button isn't disabled anymore.

Answer (score 3):

you may want to use a dispatcher, there is probably a threading problem (callback function running on seperate thread and trying to access ui which runs on another thread). try this . .

```
updateButton.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    new ThreadStart(() => updateButton.IsEnabled = false), 
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Input, null);
```

instead of

```
updateButton.IsEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't work. Even after the button is disabled, if a new thread is started inside the event handler, the disabled button continues to accept click evnets. I use Snoop to check the event and find that the click event happens after the workthread finished. But my assumption is that the button should be disabled during workthread execution with no any click event happens. I guess something is wrong but don't know how.

Comment: i think i understand. perhaps you should also add another line of inside of the thread to disable the button first (may require dispatcher), then do the work and re-enable the button again (as you have it now): private void startWorkThread()
{
     updateButton.IsEnabled = false;
    //after finish required process
    updateButton.IsEnabled = true;
}

Comment: you may have to use dispatcher for those 2 lines

Comment: Thank you. The problem was that the workthread started second thread to update UI items. I moved handling of UI items from second thread to workthread and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you were instead to change the order of your events from:

```
  updateButton.IsEnabled = false;
  startWorkThread();
```

To

```
  startWorkThread();
  updateButton.IsEnabled = false;
```

Let me know how this goes.

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like is that you are starting your thread then immediatly enabling your button before your thread has finished. You would be better off using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) and enable your Button in the RunWorkerCompleted Event. Though you can do something similar by enabling your button using a BeginInvoke at the end of your Process.

```
public void doWork()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); //Simulating your Process
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(delegate() { updateButton.IsEnabled = true; }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
}
```

**Example with BackgroundWorker**

```
using System.ComponentModel;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    BackgroundWorker bgw;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgw_DoWork);
        bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgw_RunWorkerCompleted);

    }

    void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        updateButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); //Simulating your work
    }



    private void startWorkThread()
    {
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void updateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (bgw.IsBusy != true)
        {
            updateButton.IsEnabled = false;
            startWorkThread();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work too. The button looks disabled but still accept clicks and events handled later.

Comment: @user1908842 All I can say is that it works on my system. The Button is disabled and **does not** respond to Clicks. I think you need to post the code for your startWorkThread Method. Also are you saying that the BackGroundWorker is not working also or just the first method.

Comment: BackGroundWorker is working. Only the button is not disabled.

Comment: @user1908842 The button should be disabled before you start your BackgroundWorker, and not enabled untill the RunWorkerCompleted Event fires. as I said all of the above code was tested before posting

Comment: Your program works fine. I think my workthread has some problem. Thank you.

Comment: The problem was the workthread started another thread to refresh user view.

Comment: @user1908842 Glad you found it

Comment: The problem was that the workthread started another thread to update user view.
    private void BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
            {
                System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem delegate
{ ... (System.Action)delegate()
                    {
                        startChartRevProcess();
    ...
 }
StartChartRevProcess has to handle some UI items and to be started as another thread as above.
Later I moved UI handling to workthread and started startChartRevProcess synchronously, and the problem solved.
Thank you all.